# jquery tool tip make div appear

Tags: jquery

Is there a tool tip that instead of making the title appear in it i can make information from a div appear...
what i have is a image and i want maybe an invisible div below it, so when a user hovers over the image the div appears with name address face book like in it etc?

```
<img width="448" height="300" src="/Content/uploadedImg/1.png                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          " onerror="this.src='/Content/img/redboxlrg.png';">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like -

```
<img width="448" height="300" src="/Content/uploadedImg/1.png" id="hoverimage" />
<div id="showdiv" style="display:none;">Hidden initially, because of 'display:none;'</div>
<script>
  $("#hoverimage").hover(function(){
    //this happens when you first 'hover' over the image with id = 'hoverimage'
    $("#showdiv").stop().fadeIn(500); //stop() is important, it prevents a 'queue' from building
    //the .fadeIn(n) function will fade an element in over n milliseconds
  }, function(){
    //this happens when the mouse moves out/hover ends
    $("#showdiv").stop().fadeOut(500);
    //similarly, the fadeOut(n) function fades an element out over n ms
  }
</script>
```

Note that for this, you will need to also include the jQuery library, to make use of the jQuery (or $) functionality.

See http://www.worthapost.com/articles/how-include-jquery-your-website-google for more on that

Comment: i have jquery included but this doesnt work, i need the div to be displayed on top of the image not below it

Comment: i have a gallery and adding this div messes up the layout, i would like the tooltip/div to hover hover the image

Comment: It's a very rough example, doesn't take into account any existing layout. You can try adding `style='position:absolute;'` and place it accordingly (this will require both the image and div placed inside a parent div with `style='position:relative;'`). You had mentioned in the original question that you wanted it to appear below the image

Answer (score 0):

There are several jQuery Plugins out there which can help you with that.

See this collection of jQuery Tooltip Plugins:
http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/